# Regular expression in javascript with OR condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regular expression that is able to determine //example or //www.example in the website URL . I get the url location of website by ,

```
var urlOfWeb = location.href ;
```

I created a regular expression in JavaScript which gives an irregular output when run multiple times . I tried it in firefox browser / console / Phpstorm IDE .
Here is the expression ,

```
// The regular expression
    var expToLookFor = /(\/\/example|\/\/www\.example)/g;
// Using test method of Regexp object of javascript which gives bool result
expToLookFor.test("//example") ;
// Result : true
expToLookFor.test("//example") ;
// Result : false
```

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `g` flag in your regular expression.

Comment: Also it would be simpler to do `/\/\/(?:www\.)?example/`

Comment: @siddarth there are many questions here regarding this issue. Please do a search before asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove global flag from your regex to make it:

```
var expToLookFor = /(\/\/example|\/\/www\.example)/;
```

[As `g` flag makes `RegExp` object remember it's last position `lastIndex`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

Better you refactor your regex to:

```
var expToLookFor = /\/\/(www\.)?example/;
```

Comment: Those are some ugly mountains =)

Comment: @Anubhava : It worked very well . I would have selected your answer after a minute of your posting the answer but I had to wait for 15min before I can select an answer , must be some stackoverflow rule . Anyways , Thank you .